# Python, Pandas, Numpy: Date_range: passing a np.timedelta as freq. argument

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a time delta that is in format numpy.timedelta(64):
`value = numpy.timedelta64(30,'m')`
 (here 30min).

Is there a way to pass that value to the construction of a pandas date_range:
`pd.date_range(start_time, end_time, freq=value)` ?

If not how is it possible to convert that value in order to pass it in the date_range? I tried `value.astype('str')` but it returns `'0:30:00'` that is also not suited as an argument for the pd.date_range.

Comment: Why -1? How is that a bad question? All feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert it to a `Timedelta` and pass it into `freq`.

```
>>> pd.date_range('20160101', '20170101', freq=pd.Timedelta(value)) 
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-01 00:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 01:00:00', '2016-01-01 01:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 02:00:00', '2016-01-01 02:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 03:00:00', '2016-01-01 03:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 04:00:00', '2016-01-01 04:30:00',
               ...
               '2016-12-31 19:30:00', '2016-12-31 20:00:00',
               '2016-12-31 20:30:00', '2016-12-31 21:00:00',
               '2016-12-31 21:30:00', '2016-12-31 22:00:00',
               '2016-12-31 22:30:00', '2016-12-31 23:00:00',
               '2016-12-31 23:30:00', '2017-01-01 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=17569, freq='30T')
```

I think older versions of `pandas` didn't support this, but could still use a frequency string:

```
 pd.date_range('20160101', '20170101', freq='30min')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are starting with a `numpy.timedelta64`, I wondered how `np.arange` handled this.

With `datetime64` start and stop values `arange` handles this nicely:

```
In [847]: x=np.arange(np.datetime64('2016-01-01'), np.datetime64('2017-01-01'),value)
In [848]: x
Out[848]: 
array(['2016-01-01T00:00', '2016-01-01T00:30', '2016-01-01T01:00', ...,
       '2016-12-31T22:30', '2016-12-31T23:00', '2016-12-31T23:30'], dtype='datetime64[m]')
```

and `DatetimeIndex` accepts such an array:

```
In [849]: pd.DatetimeIndex(x)
Out[849]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-01 00:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 01:00:00', '2016-01-01 01:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 02:00:00', '2016-01-01 02:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 03:00:00', '2016-01-01 03:30:00',
               '2016-01-01 04:00:00', '2016-01-01 04:30:00',
               ...
               '2016-12-31 19:00:00', '2016-12-31 19:30:00',
               '2016-12-31 20:00:00', '2016-12-31 20:30:00',
               '2016-12-31 21:00:00', '2016-12-31 21:30:00',
               '2016-12-31 22:00:00', '2016-12-31 22:30:00',
               '2016-12-31 23:00:00', '2016-12-31 23:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=17568, freq=None)
```